# Validating a condition across a set of associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have some models like

```
class System < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :factions

class Faction < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :System
```

Each faction has a controlling flag.

I need a validation that verfies each system has no more that 1 faction with controlling flag set to true.

I am trying to do this via the system model because this flag is updated via a nested form on the systems page.

I tried additing a validation like:

```
  def can_only_have_one_faction_as_controlling
    if factions.where(controlling: true).length > 1
      errors.add(:base, 'A system can only be controlled by 1 faction')
    end   end
```

However it looks like this goes all the way back to the db which has not been updated yet.  (This however does prevent resaving the item)

So I guess the question is how to I get the temporary values of children updated before it runs the parental checks?

Or am I going about this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this without going to the db via the where

```
if factions.collect{|x| x.controlling ? 1 : 0 }.sum > 1
  errors.add(:base, 'A system can only be controlled by 1 faction')
end
```

If anyone can suggest a better way to do this OOTB I am all ears.